# Insert missing numbers in ordered vector with repeated elements

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I have the following case:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
B = [1 1 1 6 8 8 10];
```

How can I create a vector C that joins A and B, inserting the missing numbers in the series but keeping the repeated numbers in A? C will look like this:

```
C = [1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 9 10];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the logical index of A in B, remove them with `~`, concatenate the resulting vectors and sort . . .

```
C=sort([A(~ismember(A,B)) B])
```